# Relative import raises ValueError

Tags: python, import, python-3.x

I Have following directory structure:

```
src
   __init__.py
   foo1
       __init__.py
      foo1.py
   foo2
     __init__.py
     foo2.py
```

Now I want to import from foo2.py the module foo1.py. In foo2.py I've imported with `from ..foo1.foo1 import *` but all I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..foo1.foo1 import *
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

How do I get this relative import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see here is that the base package, in your case `src` has not been imported, this is a necessary condition to use relative imports.

If you write an script that the `src` folder is in the `sys.path`, thus importable, which states:

```
import src #this imports the base package
from src.foo2.foo2 import *

...
```

It will work.